# how to promt a message if a field is empty in oracle forms

Tags: oracle, oracleforms

How to prompt a message if field is empty in oracle forms i'm not sure if it works and the trigger i'm using is **`when-validate-item`**

```sql
begin
  if date = NULL then
    message('please enter issue date')
  else
    null;
  end if;
end;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my point of view:

- you should edit field's properties and set the **required** property to **yes** and let Forms worry about it
- if you insist on reinventing the wheel, then don't just *display a message* as it is pretty much useless - user can ignore it. Raise an error, instead

  ```
  if :block_name.item_name is null then
      message('Please, enter issue date');
      raise_form_trigger_failure;
  end if;
  ```

  Put that piece of code into the `WHEN-VALIDATE-ITEM` trigger.

Comment: Thankyou setting property to yes solved my problem

Answer (score 1):

Just modify the code a little bit as

- converting `date = NULL` to `:date IS NULL`, since `:` prepended to
  the field's name within the code
- add an extra `message('');` (*exactly this with blank padded
  argument*) if a pop-up message box needed
- don't forget the semicolon at the end of the line of the current
  `message(....)`

as invoking from one of the **`WHEN-VALIDATE-ITEM`** or **`WHEN-NEW-ITEM-INSTANCE`** triggers